# Let $P = (0, q)$ be the hyperbolic midpoint of $A = (0, a)$ and $B = (0, a + b)$. Compute the limit of $q$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $P = (0, q)$ be the hyperbolic midpoint of $A = (0, a)$ and $B = (0, a + b)$. Compute the limit of $q$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$, as a function of the fixed number $b$.

I know this is a vertical line and that to compute the distance of a vertical line in the hyperbolic model. $AB*=|\ln(\frac{AM}{BM})|$ where $M$ is the endpoint of the line so $M=(0,0)$(and $AM$ and $BM$ are computed using the standard distance formula). Now computing the distance as $a \rightarrow \infty$ I see that the distance becomes $0$. Now I imagine as the distance goes to $0$ as $a$ gets big then the midpoint should go approach $B$ or $(0, a+b)$ yet not sure how to justify that with the limit. As of now we know that $Q=\frac{a+a+b}{2}=\frac{2a+b}{2}$ as $a$ gets bigger then the gap between $A$ and $B$ goes to $0$.

This is all taking place in the Hyperbolic/Half-Plane Model.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ hyperbolic distances? If they are, then $q=\frac{a+b}2$. If $a$ tends to the infinity and if $b$ is a constant then $q$ remains a constant. If $a$ is the Euclidean distance then it cannot tend to the $\infty$. It can go to the radius of the model.

Comment: Yes this is all in the hyperbolic half plane model. Wouldn't $q=\frac{2a+b}{2}$? I don't quite see how it should stay constant when applying the limit.

Comment: This exercise appears ridiculously trivial and suspiciously specific: *Any* point "above" $A$ in the upper half-plane gets pushed to infinity as $A$ itself heads that way. Why bother defining midpoint $P$, or calling out the "fixed number" $b$, at all? Something doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independently of the model you are using, this is a question related to absolute geometry. It is a big mistake to think that the model counts!

In absolute geometry the axioms of congruence hold. And the facts in the question are facts of absolute geometry in which the axiom of parallelism is not fixed -- it can be the Euclidean axiom or it can be the hyperbolic axiom.

What is the answer to your question in Euclidean geometry? Let's ask:

> We are in Euclidean geometry and we have a ray. Let's take a point $A$ on this ray $a$ units away from the beginning of the ray. Then we have a distance $b$ and a point $B$ on this ray $b$ units away form $A$. The midpoint's distance form the beginning of the ray is $\frac{a+b}2$. What happens to this length if $a$ tends to $\infty$? The answer is intuitive: This limit tends to the infinity because the distance of the midpoint remains the same: $\frac{a+b}2$.

$\color{white}{...}$

> The same question in hyperbolic geometry: ... The answer is also the same.

This is all independent of the models we use to intuit the geometries we examine.

(Yes, the models / the geometries. The Euclidean geometry in the usual intuition is also only a model of the axioms of Euclidean geometry.)

Comment: For this particular problem wouldn't the midpoint though be  $a+\frac{b}{2}$

Comment: The midpoint is at $a+\frac{b-a}2=a+\frac b2-\frac a2=\frac a2+\frac b2=\frac{a+b}2$.